# Can I run VMware Player and WSL2 on the same Windows 10 Pro machine without disabling either?

Tags: vmware-player, wsl2, windows-10-pro

Its not super clear to me from searches done if I can run VMware Player on the same Windows 10 Pro machine using Docker / WSL2 to run Linux containers. Or does it mean Hyper-V needs to be disabled to run one with implication that the other cannot be run simultaneously?

Comment: WSL2 can coexist on a system with VMWare since it doesn’t require Hyper-V to be enabled.  This is only true with current versions of VMWare (16.x) and Windows 10 20H2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about VMware Player but VMware Workstation V16 newest and Windows 10 Pro newest are making progress toward co-existence with Microsoft Virtualization.

All you can do is try your setup and see if it works. My experience is that the worst outcome is having to reinstall VMware Workstation and/or Player.